# PyQGIS - Data Source is Invalid

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

Why I am getting `Data Source is Invalid` in python console of QGIS when running:

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("home/sanjayr/Desktop/india-latest.shp/buildings.shp","sanjay","ogr")
```

I am using QGIS 2.4 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Maybe the system does not know if it should open india-latest.shp as a file, or buildings.shp. Try to rename the folder.

Comment: I treid with this also `/home/sanjayr/Desktop/osm data/malaysia/intersectpnt.shp`. but not working.

Comment: You have the .shx and .dbf file also in the same folder? Without them QGIS can not read the shapefile. Can you load the files manually?

Comment: Yes It was there in same folder with .shx and .dbf. I checked the shape file loading manually ..it is okay.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958416/how-to-create-a-qgsvectorlayer-in-qgis-in-centos-maybe-missing-plugins-package

Comment: I doubt something similar to path variable. But I don't know exactly.I want to learn pyQGIS. I am just following Documention of pyQGIS. http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/

Comment: I make that piece code code working adding `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)`

`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it is working but these piece of code works.

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("home/sanjayr/Desktop/india-latest.shp/buildings.shp","sanjay","ogr")

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Comment: But I noticed layer is added but not visible. Attribute table is opening. I tried zoom to layer and refresh the window. But it is not visible. what is issue..?

Comment: It solved checking `render`in http://i.stack.imgur.com/tRWdK.png